# batch set /p "id= type id: " not working

Tags: batch-file, command-line, set

I have this in my batch file

```
set /p "id=type id: "

echo you typed %id%
pause
```

but echo just prints you typed and NOTHING else.

I have looked around the forum, and tried := %=% =  but nothing makes any difference

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as it!
Try it, paste it to an empty file and it works.

But I assume it's only a part of a bigger batch file, inside a code block.
That is the cause that it fails.

You could use delayed expansion

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
set /p "id=type id: "
echo you typed !id!
)
```